# Unable to pass state from reducer to 'this.props', fetching API using axios on React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, axios

Hi I'm very new to React and this is my first project, what I'm trying to do is when onClick, the code will fetch data from API using Axios and display the object.

First, I tried using a reducer and failed. Read on Redux docs, that the way to resolve when dealing with asynchronous actions we to use [applymiddleware](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware). So after trying and adjusting I end up with:

```
// I KNOW... YOU MIGHT BE THINKING WHY REDUX FOR SUCH A SIMPLE APP, WHY NOT JUST USE REACT?? IT'S SUCH AN OVER-KILL. WELL... I FORCE MYSELF TO IMPLEMENT IT ON THE FIRST PROJECT TO UNDERSTAND AND DEMONSTRATE THE FUNCTIONALITY OF REACT, REDUX AND REACT-REDUX. SIMPLE APP IS IT CLEARER/OBVIOUS.

const thunk = ReduxThunk.default;
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware } = Redux;
const GENERATE = 'GENERATE';

class QuoteGenerator extends React.Component {
  generateQuote = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(generateNewQuote());
  };

  generate = () => {
    this.props.dispatch({
      type: GENERATE,
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.quote}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.generate}>Generate</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  quote: state.quote,
});

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps)(QuoteGenerator);

/**************************************************************/

const initState = {
  quote: 'Generate Me!',
};

function fetchQuote() {
  return axios.get(
    'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json'
  );
}

function returnQuote(quote) {
  return {
    quote: quote,
  };
}

// But what do you do when you need to start an asynchronous action,
// such as an API call, or a router transition?

// Meet thunks. 
// A thunk is a function that returns a function.
// This is a thunk.
function generateNewQuote(state = initState, action) {
  //   if (action.type === GENERATE) {
  //     console.log("It Works")
  // Invert control!
  // Return a function that accepts `dispatch` so we can dispatch later.
  // Thunk middleware knows how to turn thunk async actions into actions.
  return function (dispatch) {
    return fetchQuote().then((res) => {
      const selectRandomQuote = Math.floor(
        Math.random() * res.data.quotes.length
      );
      const quoteObj = {
        quote: res.data.quotes[selectRandomQuote]['quote'],
        author: res.data.quotes[selectRandomQuote]['author'],
      };
      console.log({ quote: res.data.quotes[selectRandomQuote]['quote'] });
      return { quote: res.data.quotes[selectRandomQuote]['quote'] };
    });
  };
  //   } else {
  //     return state;
  //   }
}

function reducer(state = initState, action) {
  if (action.type === GENERATE) {
    return {
      quote: 'It Works!',
    };
  } else {
    return state;
  }
}

// applyMiddleware supercharges createStore with middleware:
const store = createStore(generateNewQuote, applyMiddleware(thunk));

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Container />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I'm able to trigger the function and console log the output but with no luck, it's not showing...

I really appreciate the guidance to share some light on this, been really keen on React but the first has hit me hard. Thanks in advance, cheers!

Comment: You are confusing quite a few things here, the biggest problem that you somehow gave your thunk the signature of a reducer (a thunk does not change state!).
Generally: you are writing a style of Redux that is outdated by many years here. If you are just learning Redux, please stop following that tutorial and go with the official Redux tutorial instead: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts
Also, in 2021 you should avoid writing class components - if you are just learning that, that tutorial is also very outdated.